# For and Enhanced For Loop Giving different Outputs in Java recursion Problem

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

So There is a Problem Of recursion I was solving but output seems to be different using Regular for loop and enhanced for loop enhanced for loop gives right Answer.

The Commented Part is Not Working correctly in place of enhanced for loop just below It

Problem is This - 1. You are given a number n and a number m representing number of rows and columns in a maze.
2. You are standing in the top-left corner and have to reach the bottom-right corner.
3. In a single move you are allowed to jump 1 or more steps horizontally (as h1, h2, .. ), or 1 or more steps vertically (as v1, v2, ..) or 1 or more steps diagonally (as d1, d2, ..).
4. Complete the body of getMazePath function - without changing signature - to get the list of all paths that can be used to move from top-left to bottom-right.
Use sample input and output to take idea about output.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        
        Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n=sn.nextInt();
        int m=sn.nextInt();
        
        ArrayList<String> ll=getMazePaths(0,0,n,m);
        System.out.println(ll);
        

    }
    
    public static ArrayList<String> getMazePaths(int sr, int sc, int dr, int dc) {
        

        
        if(sr==dr-1 && sc==dc-1){
            ArrayList<String> nl=new ArrayList<>();
            nl.add("");
            return nl;
        }
        

        ArrayList<String> ral=new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i=1;i<=dc-sc;i++){
            
            ArrayList<String> hl=getMazePaths(sr,sc+i,dr,dc);
           
          
            
            //This Should Work the Same as The Enhanced For loop Below it but its not producing same 
            //output 
              
            // for(int j=0;i<hl.size();j++){
            //     ral.add("h"+i+hl.get(j));
            // }
            
             for(String p:hl){
               ral.add("h"+i+p);
           }
            
        }
        
        for(int i=1;i<=dr-sr;i++){
            
        ArrayList<String> vl=getMazePaths(sr+i,sc,dr,dc);
            
            // for(int j=0;i<vl.size();j++){
            //     ral.add("v"+i+vl.get(j));
            // }
            
            for(String p:vl){
               ral.add("v"+i+p);
           }
            
        }
        
    for(int i=1;i<=dc-sc && i<=dr-sr ;i++){
            
            ArrayList<String> dl=getMazePaths(sr+i,sc+i,dr,dc);
            
            // for(int j=0;i<dl.size();j++){
            //     String ss=dl.get(j);
            //     ral.add("d"+i+ss);
            // }
            
             for(String p:dl){
              ral.add("d"+i+p);
          }
            
        }
    
        return ral;
    }
```

Comment: "It is not producing the same output" - what output does either give?

Comment: on Imputting 2 3 Output is `[h1h1v1, h1v1h1, h1d1, h2v1, v1h1h1, v1h2, d1h1]` This Is Correct Output Given by the Enhanced For Loop and the Normal For loop is Giving This `[]
` That is Empty List

Comment: You have `for(int j=0;i<hl.size();j++){`, you mean `for(int j=0;j<hl.size();j++){`. Note `i` and `j` are different.

Comment: Ohh Thanks Got It

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the i instead of j :

this :

```
// for(int j=0;i<hl.size();j++){
            //     ral.add("h"+i+hl.get(j));
            // }
```

should be :

```
for(int j=0;j<hl.size();j++){
   ral.add("h"+i+hl.get(j));
}
```